# What is the valid form of alias names?

Tags: bash, unix, alias

I'm trying to implement a basic behavior for alias command in bash, I just want to know the valid form of the names.

Comment: The OP, I think, is just asking what constitutes a valid alias name. "The characters /,
       $, `, and = and any of the shell metacharacters or  quoting  characters
       listed above may not appear in an alias name."

Comment: What does OP mean?

Comment: "Original poster"; in this case, you :)

Answer (score 1):

I took a peek at the Bash source, and @chepner's comment is correct. Any characters that aren't interpreted by the shell already are valid. So things like `$`, `/`, and `=` are not allowed.

From general.c, https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-5.0.tar.gz

```c
/* Return 1 if STRING comprises a valid alias name.  The shell accepts
   essentially all characters except those which must be quoted to the
   parser (which disqualifies them from alias expansion anyway) and `/'. */
int
legal_alias_name (string, flags)
     const char *string;
     int flags;
{
  register const char *s;

  for (s = string; *s; s++)
    if (shellbreak (*s) || shellxquote (*s) || shellexp (*s) || (*s == '/'))
      return 0;
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: by the way, thanks for source code. I've been looking for it for since.